# Core data relationships mystery

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

The simple app I'm building to expose the gaps in my beginner's understanding of Core Data relationships is doing just that. Here's a brief description:

The app has three views: `HomeViewController`, `AddViewController`, and `AddCategoryViewController`.

My data model has two Entities, with relationships like this:

[image]

New `WMDGCategory` objects are added via a textfield in `AddCategoryViewController` and new `WMDGActivity` objects are added via a textfield in `AddViewController`.

My goal is to be able to display WMDGActivity objects in the tableview in HomeViewController, grouped under sections defined by WMDGCategory objects.

Currently, when I fire it up in the sim, no crash, but I get this error stack:

```
2014-03-03 12:39:07.893 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0x2f80ac) -> Created Context UNNAMED
2014-03-03 12:39:07.895 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x2f80ac) Set Root Saving Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8dadea0>
2014-03-03 12:39:07.899 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_newMainQueueContext](0x2f80ac) Created Main Queue Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8aa4180>
2014-03-03 12:39:07.900 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x2f80ac) Set Default Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8aa4180>
2014-03-03 12:39:07.916 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) object <WMDGActivity: 0x8aabff0> (entity: WMDGActivity; id: 0x8aac930 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGActivity/p1> ; data: {
    category = nil;
    name = Programming;
    toCategory = nil;
}) returned nil value for section name key path 'toCategory.name'. Object will be placed in unnamed section
2014-03-03 12:39:07.917 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) object <WMDGActivity: 0x8aad520> (entity: WMDGActivity; id: 0x8aac940 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGActivity/p2> ; data: {
    category = nil;
    name = "New Workplace Activity";
    toCategory = nil;
}) returned nil value for section name key path 'toCategory.name'. Object will be placed in unnamed section
```

When I add a new activity and assign it to an existing category using this code:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (self.activityField.text.length > 0)
    {

        if (self.categoryLabel.text.length < 1)
        {
            self.thisCategory.name = @"Uncategorized";
        }

        else
        {
        self.thisCategory.name = self.categoryLabel.text;
        self.thisActivity.name = self.activityField.text;
        self.thisActivity.toCategory.name = self.categoryLabel.text;

        NSLog(@"Category name is %@", self.thisCategory.name);
        NSLog(@"Activity name is %@", self.thisActivity.name);
        }


        [self.delegate addViewControllerDidSave];

    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No activity entered"
                                                        message:@"Please enter a new activity or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }   
}
```

Nothing shows up in my tableview, and I get this error call stack:

```
2014-03-03 13:08:24.321 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Number of categories is 2
2014-03-03 13:08:24.323 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Number of categories is 2
2014-03-03 13:08:24.328 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Number of categories is 2
2014-03-03 13:08:24.329 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Number of categories is 2
2014-03-03 13:08:24.333 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Title of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8ac0c20> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8ac4640 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGCategory/p2> ; data: <fault>)
2014-03-03 13:08:24.335 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Title of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8ac0e00> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8ac4730 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGCategory/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2014-03-03 13:08:24.338 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Title of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8ac0c20> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8ac4640 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGCategory/p2> ; data: {
    activities = "<relationship fault: 0x8ad7ca0 'activities'>";
    name = Sports;
})
2014-03-03 13:08:24.339 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Title of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8ac0e00> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8ac4730 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGCategory/p1> ; data: {
    activities = "<relationship fault: 0x8dc0520 'activities'>";
    name = WORKPLACE;
})
2014-03-03 13:08:24.342 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Title of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8ac0c20> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8ac4640 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGCategory/p2> ; data: {
    activities = "<relationship fault: 0x8ad7ca0 'activities'>";
    name = Sports;
})
2014-03-03 13:08:29.393 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Title of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8ac0e00> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8ac4730 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGCategory/p1> ; data: {
    activities = "<relationship fault: 0x8dc0520 'activities'>";
    name = WORKPLACE;
})
2014-03-03 13:12:08.187 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Category name is (null)
2014-03-03 13:12:08.187 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] Activity name is Meeting
2014-03-03 13:12:11.077 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8aa4180) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x8aa4180): *** DEFAULT ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2014-03-03 13:12:11.077 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8aa4180) → Save Parents? 1
2014-03-03 13:12:11.078 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8aa4180) → Save Synchronously? 1
2014-03-03 13:12:11.078 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x8aa4180) Context DEFAULT is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 1 inserted objects
2014-03-03 13:12:11.081 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8dadea0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x8dadea0): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2014-03-03 13:12:11.082 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8dadea0) → Save Parents? 1
2014-03-03 13:12:11.082 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8dadea0) → Save Synchronously? 1
2014-03-03 13:12:11.083 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x8dadea0) Context BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 1 inserted objects
2014-03-03 13:12:11.085 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke25(0x8dadea0) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0x8dadea0): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2014-03-03 13:12:11.088 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) object <WMDGActivity: 0x8aabff0> (entity: WMDGActivity; id: 0x8aac930 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGActivity/p1> ; data: {
    category = nil;
    name = Programming;
    toCategory = nil;
}) returned nil value for section name key path 'toCategory.name'. Object will be placed in unnamed section
2014-03-03 13:12:11.088 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) object <WMDGActivity: 0x8aad520> (entity: WMDGActivity; id: 0x8aac940 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGActivity/p2> ; data: {
    category = nil;
    name = "New Workplace Activity";
    toCategory = nil;
}) returned nil value for section name key path 'toCategory.name'. Object will be placed in unnamed section
2014-03-03 13:12:11.097 EntitiesAndRelationships[323:a0b] CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) object <WMDGActivity: 0x8a87970> (entity: WMDGActivity; id: 0x8acabc0 <x-coredata://126C2FFD-8184-43B1-AA4D-AEFBE1AAC1A1/WMDGActivity/p3> ; data: {
    category = nil;
    name = Meeting;
    toCategory = nil;
}) returned nil value for section name key path 'toCategory.name'. Object will be placed in unnamed section
```

I know this is long, and I much appreciate your time in helping me out. I'm committed to understanding this.

Thanks!

**Edit--response to answer below by Wain**

I modified my code like so, which I thought addressed both your points, i.e,

1) `thisCategory` is a `WMDGCategory` property of self

2) And I thought the modified code in the `else` statement below would fix the `toCategory` problem

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (self.activityField.text.length > 0)
    {

        if (self.categoryLabel.text.length < 1)
        {
            self.thisCategory.name = @"Uncategorized";
        }

        else
        {
        self.thisCategory.name = self.categoryLabel.text;
        self.thisActivity.name = self.activityField.text;
        self.thisActivity.toCategory.name = self.thisCategory.name;

        NSLog(@"Category name is %@", self.thisCategory.name);
        NSLog(@"Activity name is %@", self.thisActivity.name);
        }


        [self.delegate addViewControllerDidSave];

    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No activity entered"
                                                        message:@"Please enter a new activity or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```

However, I still get the same readout--some variant of:

```
category = nil;
name = Zoomba;
toCategory = nil;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you set `self.thisActivity.toCategory.name`, you generally shouldn't be and you never actually set `self.thisActivity.toCategory`.

Objects don't exist unless you create them. And relationships don't contain objects unless you set them. Your issue appears to be that you are never actually creating (or, getting an existing one at least) a `WMDGCategory` instance that you can connect to your `WMDGActivity`.

So, when you try to use the relationship contents in the FRC, you get a `nil`. (you can see in your log that it repeatedly says `toCategory = nil;`).

Fix that by setting the `toCategory` of your activities to `WMDGCategory` instances.

Comment: Thanks, Wain! Please see edit above. Despite having made mods that I thought reflected your guidance, apparently not. Still same readout, with the relationships set to nil.

Comment: Where do you set `thisCategory`? And then `thisActivity.toCategory`? You're still just setting the name, you need to create an object first and then set the relationship. To get the logs you have you must create objects somewhere, pass a pointer to one of those to `thisCategory`

Comment: I guess I must seem pretty obtuse, but I just plain don't get it. I don't want to wear out my welcome, but I'm pretty green and sometimes need a kick over the speed bump. A line or two of code would sure help me to understand exactly what you mean by passing a pointer to thisCategory, if you're so disposed. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Somewhere you need to add `self.thisActivity = self.thisCategory`. But, before that, `this.thisCategory` needs to be set to an instance of `WMDGCategory`. It isn't clear if you have any of that working so far. So, where have you set `self.thisCategory = ...` and what did you set it to (use NSLog to check what it is set to).

Comment: - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.thisCategory = [frc.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];
}  Sorry--I don't know how to format in a comment.

Comment: Ok, so where you currently have `self.thisActivity.toCategory.name = self.thisCategory.name;`, remove `.name` so you are setting the existing category you have into the relationship (`toCategory`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48975/discussion-between-tim-jones-and-wain)